# javascript query string for multiple buttons

Tags: javascript, string, button, get

Hi I am trying to create a query string similar to the one available here:
http://andrewu.co.uk/tools/request/examples/example1.html

The problem that I am having is that I have more than one button on my page and even though my id's are unique all of my data is displaying on the action page at the same time. The code that i am using for my buttons is:

```
<label for="name_1">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name_1" tabindex="1" size="40" value="Donald Duck" />

        <br />
        <br />

        <input type="submit" id='view1' value="Submit" tabindex="2" />
        <label for="name_1">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name_2" tabindex="1" size="40" value="Mickey Mouse" />

        <br />
        <br />

        <input type="submit" id='view2' value="View" tabindex="2" />
```

I have a lot more than 2 buttons on my page. when a button is clicked  I would like to see a result like what is on this page:

http://andrewu.co.uk/tools/request/examples/example1_process.html?name=Andrew+Urquhart

but instead I am getting Name: Donald Duck, Name: Mickey Mouse. What would I have to add or change to obtain just one Name to display at a time but have it be different depending on which button is pressed?

Answer (score 0):

The button is simply submitting the form it is contained in. It's not tied to any particular field.

If you only want one name/value pair to be sent to the server, you'll need separate form elements:

```
<form id="name_1_form">
  <input name="name" value="Andrew" />
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>

<form id="name_2_form">
  <input name="name" value="Mickey" />
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem with your form is that both inputs have name="name"
and when you submit the form both are send.

you can either:

- use different names for you input and select the correct one based on the pressed button, or
- use 2 forms, one for each button
- use javascript to send the correct data (this can help: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/, http://api.jquery.com/submit/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="submit" id='view1' name="Name" value="Mickey Mouse" tabindex="2" />
<input type="submit" id='view2' name="Name" value="Donald Duck" tabindex="2" />
```

or

```
<input type="text" name="name_1" id="name_1" tabindex="1" size="40" value="Donald Duck" />
<input type="submit" id='view1' name="Name" value="Submit" onClick="this.name=this.form.name_1.value" tabindex="2" />

<input type="text" name="name_2" id="name_2" tabindex="1" size="40" value="Mickey Mouse" />
<input type="submit" id='view2' name="Name" value="View" onClick="this.value=this.form.name_2.value" tabindex="2" />
```

you can disable the input if you do not want to send the name it twice

Comment: Hi I am stilling seeing two names on my second screen. I think it is because the script on the second page: <script type="text/javascript">
   
   document.write("Name: " + Request.QueryString("name"));
   
  </script>
is looking for name even thought I renamed them to name='name1' and name='name2'

Comment: I changed it to Name, since name is a reserved word.